# Interpretation for other characteristic classes

Tags: differential-geometry

The Euler characteristics ($\chi$) is perhaps the most well-known in physics and it counts the number of holes in a given manifold or more technically its genus. But there are other characteristic classes as well, do they have such similar geometric interpretations? (E.g. Todd class, Pontragyin Class etc.)

Comment: @NiharKarve People on that site are very rude.

Comment: Okay. Well here's a similar question on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/222604

Comment: @NiharKarve Thanks I will have a look.

Comment: You seem to be thinking only of (real) surfaces in your interpretation of the Euler characteristic. The interpretation as the sum of indices of a vector field (generic section of the tangent bundle) is the direction to think to generalize to Chern and Pontryagin classes of appropriate bundles. Todd classes are a bit more formal.